# Is there a way to compare two web pages or tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, comparison

I have a website that offers me a "preview" mode, and a "live" mode of a document. I can open each in their own tab in Chrome. I'd like to know if there is a way to compare the two in Chrome, perhaps with a browser plugin or chrome extension or something. Is this possible, and if so, are there any tools?

I searched and was unable to find anything, but it seems like something might exist.

Comment: what kind of document are you viewing? Could you specify? If they are just html sites, then you could download and compare them with an text editor (e.g. vim, notepad++)